# CSS/JS errors clogging Visual Studio 2015 Error List in C# MVC Project

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015

I have started using ASP.NET Core with Visual Studio 2015, and have been getting frustrated with the error list.

With visual studio 2013 only C# errors would show, but visual studio 2015 errors from js and css (which often come from minified libraries and packages i have imported) are clogging the area.

It wont stop the build, but it is annoying having to sift through them to find the CS errors.

I have looked up on google and here to find the answer, but am unable to find a solution.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

I found the answer 5 minutes after posting bounty.

In the error list next to filters I had Build + intellisense on, once I changed that to only "BUILD" it gave the desired result

[image]